# Number formatting in SAS : How to create a number list with 01, 02,

Tags: numbers, sas

I am working with sas, and I have a program I have made I want to run on a series of databases which are indexed by 01, 02 until 95 in characters ! (they correspond to different geographical areas).
I have created my program and would like to use a %lanc macro, but I would like to know if there is a better way thant

---

```
%lanc(area=01) 

%lanc(area=02)

...

%lanc(area=95)
```

---

My problem is therefore

1. How to add a zero before a number with the DO TO proc (or is there a better way ?)
2. How to convert these numbers in characters

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a macro loop, create a copy of the loop counter but formatted to z2., then pass that into your macro call...

```
%MACRO LOOPER ;
  %DO LN = 1 %TO 95 ;
    %LET Z2 = %SYSFUNC(putn(&LN,z2.)) ; /* format &LN in z2. */
    %LANC(AREA=&Z2) ;
  %END ;
%MEND ;
%LOOPER ;
```